# Recording elapsed time duration of more events in web application

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, dom-events

I have a form to be filled in my web application and this form has different steps before hitting the submit button. Like this:

1. enter name
2. enter value 1
3. enter value 2.
4. enter value 3

....

and finally submit

and I want to calculate the time taken from step 1 to 2 from 2 to 3 ...and finally to submit

I tried to implement this with Google analytic extended event tracking `TimeTracker()`

look here http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerWrappers.html but no successes.

If someone has any idea how to impalement this can give suggestions

Comment: Take a look at my answer to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463280/clicktale-like-implementation-on-google-analytics